# How to change the font of one letter?

Tags: fonts

I was wondering if it was possible to change the font of one letter in my Latex document ?

I have an equation where I want one of the letters in that to be Arial instead of Times New Roman, which is my main font.

So, is it possible ?

Comment: `\textsf{A}`rial  (depending on your setup, the A would be Arial or Helvetica, but [the difference is almost unnoticeable](http://www.ironicsans.com/helvarialquiz/))

Comment: @JLDiaz I got 19/20! Mattel was too hard for me.